# removing comments from a text file

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

Here is the sample text

| An English stop word list. Comments begin with vertical bar. Each stop
 | word is at the start of a line.

| Many of the forms below are quite rare (e.g. "yourselves") but included for
 |  completeness.

```
       | PRONOUNS FORMS
         | 1st person sing
```

i              | subject, always in upper case of course

me             | object

my             | possessive adjective

I want to remove all the text occurring on the right side of bar, including the bar itself, I have little difficulty in regular expression.

Here is the code I have been trying

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Masood\\Desktop\\IR\\Programming\\Material\\stopwords.txt");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    String source2 = null;
    while ( (line=br.readLine()) != null) {
        line.replaceAll("[|(.*)]","");
        sb.append(line);
    }

    String source = sb.toString();    
    System.out.println(source);
```

I output are the strings ''i me my'', everything else should be gone

Comment: Try this regex expression: [|](.*)[\n]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `String` is immutable, hence you need to assign `replaceAll` value to `line` itself.
2. You need to escape `|` within your regex since `|` is a regular expression itself (`\\|`)
3. You don't have to use a character class - enclosing within square brackets as it would find your `|` and just replace it

Code (staying close to your `regex`):

```
String line = "i | subject, always in upper case of course";
line = line.replaceAll("\\|(.*)","");
System.out.println(line);
```

Output:

```
i
```

Regex explanation:
http://regex101.com/r/gY6wE1

Answer (score 1):

This regexp does match the part behind | including |.

```
\|.+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that you can adapt to your situation, use the substring method and pass the beggining index and the index of the occurence of the vertical bar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "i | subject, always in upper case of course";

    String b = "me | object";

    String c = "my | possessive adjective";

    System.out.println(a.substring(0, a.indexOf('|')));
    System.out.println(b.substring(0, b.indexOf('|')));
    System.out.println(c.substring(0, c.indexOf('|')));
}
```

Output:

```
i 
me 
my
```